# How to avoid TYPO3 caching of table mapping for the whole multi website installation?

Tags: caching, mapping, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I have one TYPO3 installation 7.6.22 with different websites, each in own page trees.

In an own extension normally a certain object is persisted in table tx_myextension_domain_model_name.

But for one website A I need to map this object on another table A. So I defined the typoscript
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.MyVendor\Myextension\Domain\Model\Name.mapping ...
in a separate extension especially for this website A.

This works but its not possible at the moment to have both mappings parallel.

If I - after clearing all caches - load the plugin in the frontend of website A, all other websites have the mapping on table A (and not on tx_myextension_domain_model_name).

If I - after clearing all caches - load the plugin in the frontend of one of the other websites, everything is ok on this website, but website A produces an error, because some processes doesn't work with the default table tx_myextension_domain_model_name.

So obviously somewhere the mapping configuration is cached for the whole installation, not on a per website base.
Is that a bug or a feature? And is there a way to work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this issue in TYPO3 forge and my comment at the very bottom.

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75399#change-337355

Clearly: You need to disable the property mapper cache.
In your AdditionalConfiguration.php file add the following.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations']['extbase_datamapfactory_datamap']['backend'] = 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Backend\NullBackend';
```

This will cost you probably some performance, but I do not think it will be that much. But you will be able to configure different mappings for different sites using (local) TypoScript setup.

Comment: Thank you, Artur - that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In one installation you only can use one set of classes/ PHP sources/ extensions.
If you want different behaviour you need to insert conditions. you might split usage in your controller, and you might do some twists to split it in your repository. BUt I think that could be very complicated.

Probably the cleanest solution is to use another data domain with it's own data records.

Comment: The problem is not of classes/ PHP sources/ extensions.The only problem is that the typoscript configuration for the table mapping can not be used on a per website base as you can normally do with other typoscript. At least I don't know how it is possible. Btw., I already split the usage in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Should it only another table to seperate the entries? 
Why not working with the `pid` field to define different storages for different pages?

If it should different source code, then "simple" copy this extension and rename it.

Edit:

You can also use different domain models per website, so you have different repositories and tables for each domain.

Extend you main model to an new model (`Model1DomainB extends Model1()`) and copy the sql in `ext_tables.sql` to create the new table (`tx_extension_domain_model_model1domainb`).

Now set an setting to your plugin to define an switchable value:

```
plugin.tx_extension.settings.domain = b
```

And in your controller you can make an switch to use the correct repository:

```
switch ($this->settings['domain']) {
  case 'b':
    $models = $this->model1DomainBRepository->findAll();
  case 'c':
    $models = $this->model1DomainCRepository->findAll();
  case 'd':
    $models = $this->model1DomainDRepository->findAll();
  default:
    $models = $this->model1Repository->findAll();
    break;
}
```

Comment: There is transitionally an import of the data records for Website A from a separate database with different table structure. That the reason I want to hold it separate and the reason for mapping the table. It's a quite big installation with more than 50 websites and I want to avoid any unexpected side effects from the import. But I will think about copying the extension if there is no other solution.

Comment: Maybe different domain models per domain which extend the first model so you dont have to define to properties again. Then you can use different repositories and different tables. Of course you have also to define the used repository (eg. plugin settings per domain `plugin.tx_extension.setting.domain = 1`) and an switch in your controller.

Comment: I have added my latest suggest to my answer with more details.

Comment: The suggest from Artur Cichosz has solved my problem. But if there are perfomance issues I will try your suggest to extend the domain model. I think that should work to. Thank you for participating.